# Tesseract-OCR cannot capture '[' and ']'

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract text part of an image using Tesseract-OCR and OpenCV in Python. I have attached a simple image as below. I have created this image on paint which means there is no noise or pre-processing needs.

[image]

**Scenario 1:**

```
import pytesseract
plainText = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(testScreenshot), lang='tur', config=tessdata_dir_config)
print(plainText)
```

**Output:**

```
İtestöü)
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
import pytesseract
plainText = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(testScreenshot), lang='eng', config=tessdata_dir_config)
print(plainText)
```

**Output:**

```
[testou]
```

Still, I cannot capture very simple text properly. If I change the language settings, it captures parenthesis but miss the Turkish characters which is acceptable. However, the one with Turkish settings (Scenario 1) is not acceptable because it is missing parentheses. Any suggestions?

```
tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20200328
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
```

Comment: It should be about training dataset of different languages. Its normal to work more properly in English. Maybe it can work firstly working with Turkish language to detect the letters then working with English dataset to detect signs.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Thanks for the comment. I have already placed the file of trained data for Turkish language. This means to me that it should be able to extract letters, digits and signs at least on noise clear case. I don't think so it is acceptable as I have explained through the main question. It might be related with some settings; however, I could not find a way so far. Your suggestion looks good for the given minimal example, but it is not worthwhile to try on my actual problem.

Comment: Is this specific to ']' sign or it also not able to detect other signs too?

Comment: Works fine with some of the signs, but parenthesis or similar signs are problematic!